# MVC formcollection not showing all controls

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, formcollection

MVC formcollection not showing all controls

```
    [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(EmployeeJOBModel EmployeeJOB, FormCollection Formcoll, string Module_Name)
    {
    }
```

object Formcoll showing only two controls from below code:

CODE:

Employee Info

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee_Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Employee_Name, new { @readonly = "readOnly" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_Name)
    </div>

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Employee Job Assignment</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client_Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client_Name)*@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client_Name)
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.DropDownList("ClientName", ViewData["ClientName"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @onchange = "Call_Client_Changefunc(this.value," + ViewData["Employee_ID"] + ")" })
        }

    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Component_Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Component_Name)*@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Component_Name)
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {  
            @Html.DropDownList("Component_Name", ViewData["Component_Name"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @onchange = "Call_Component_Changefunc(this.value," + ViewData["Employee_ID"] + ")" })
        }
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Module_Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Module_Name)
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {              
            @Html.DropDownList("Module_Name", ViewData["Module_Name"] as List<SelectListItem>)                           
        }
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

---

from Above it shows only `ClientName` and `Employee_ID` 
why can anybody help me?